# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC, JSON response for not authorized

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have a site that is configured for .NET 5 with ASP.NET Core MVC. One of my controllers returns JSON results that need to have a user authenticated to access.

When I call these with an authenticated user it returns the JSON result correctly from the controller.

When I call them not authenticated I get redirected to my log on page. This is not a correct response for what is expected to be a JSON response.

What is the correct way to return a not authorized (HTTP 401) when a user is not authorized to access a JSON response in a controller in ASP.NET Core MVC?

I want my client side AJAX handler to catch the 401 code and handle it appropriately not get a HTML response back when it's expecting a JSON content type.

JSON action in the controller

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult JsonTest()
{
    return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Test", IntId = 100 });
}
```

and simple authentication setup

```
using jsontest2.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

When you call the JsonTest action with authorization it returns a JSON result correctly, when you do it not logged in which I expect a 401 I get a redirection 302 to the log in page

Comment: What does the raw not authenticated response look like? And show us your client-side code which makes and handles the request.

Comment: When the request is not authenticated it returns a HTTP status code of 302 Redirect and redirects to the HTML Login page, which is not preferred if your client expects a JSON response... I did this with just a simple test using a JSON result

 [Authorize]
        public IActionResult JsonTest()
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Test", IntId = 100 });
        }

right now there is no client side code, I'm just doing tests with direct calls to get the HTTP status code and result but my client side code will be a normal AJAX jQuery check for 401 status